# Rails PostgreSql store multidimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-models

Is it possible to store a multidimensional array in a column.

I have tried the following and received the error below coming from creating the records column.

> migration_file.rb

```
create_table :balance_sheets_details do |t|
  t.string :headers, array: true, default: []
  t.string :records, array: true, default: [[]]
  t.timestamps
end
```

Raised error

> PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{{}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs on arrays (emphasis added):

> The syntax for CREATE TABLE allows the exact size of arrays to be specified, for example:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE tictactoe (
>     squares   integer[3][3]
> );
> ```
>
> However, the current implementation ignores any supplied array size limits, i.e., the behavior is the same as for arrays of unspecified length.
>
> **The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of dimensions either.** Arrays of a particular element type are all considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of dimensions. So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in `CREATE TABLE` is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time behavior.

Thus, there isn't really a multidimensional array type. To fix your issue, just change the default from `{{}}` to `{}`.

This means a `varchar[][]` is the same type as a `varchar[]`:

```
db=# select pg_typeof(a), pg_typeof(b) from (values ('{{hello},{world}}'::varchar[][], '{foo}'::varchar[])) x(a, b);
      pg_typeof      |      pg_typeof
---------------------+---------------------
 character varying[] | character varying[]
(1 row)
```

You will still be able to store multidimensional data, though.

A one and two dimensional array are not the same:

```
db=# select '{{foo}}'::varchar[] = '{foo}'::varchar[];
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)
```